# locationManager didUpdateLocations crashing in suspend mode

Tags: swift, cllocationmanager, locationmanager

When my screen has been locked more than 10 seconds or so and my location changes, didUpdateLocations is triggered but the code stops executing about half-way through.  Specifically, it stops at the line: print("locationManager: triggering toggleStatus").  It executes the print statement but doesn't go further.  I tried replacing the call to the eco?.toggleStatus() function with other code and it still stops after the print statement.  No matter what the code below the print statement is.  locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates is set to true.

I'm using a real iPhone to test this code. I noted thatthe code runs the whole way through (including calling and executing toggleStatus()) on the simulator when the simulator is in locked mode.  I'm guessing that's because the simulator is only putting the app into background mode as opposed to suspending it but I'm not sure.

One other thing to note: I tested this code on my iPhone several weeks ago, and it appeared to work fine, including while the phone was locked.  After a few weeks, I noticed that it was stopping at the print statement.

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    let location = locations[locations.count - 1]

    if location.horizontalAccuracy > 0 {

        var latitude = round(location.coordinate.latitude*1000000)/1000000
        let longitude = round(location.coordinate.longitude*1000000)/1000000
        print("locationManager: latitude is: \(latitude)")
        print("locationManager: longitude is: \(longitude)")


        if settingNewHomeLocation == true {
            keychain.set(String(format:"%f", latitude), forKey: "bLatitude", withAccess: .accessibleAlways)
            keychain.set(String(format:"%f", longitude), forKey: "bLongitude", withAccess: .accessibleAlways)
            print("base latitude is: \(keychain.get("bLatitude")!)")
            print("base longitude is: \(keychain.get("bLongitude")!)")
            settingNewHomeLocation = false
        }

        if keychain.get("bLatitude") != nil { 

            let bLatitude = Double(keychain.get("bLatitude")!)
            let bLongitude = Double(keychain.get("bLongitude")!)

            let baseLocation = CLLocation(latitude: bLatitude!, longitude: bLongitude!)
            let distance = CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude).distance(from: baseLocation)
            print("locationManager: distance is: \(distance)")

            if distance > 100 {

                print("locationManager: triggering toggleStatus")
                eco?.toggleStatus()
            }

        } else {
            print("No home location set")
        }
    }
}
```

**SOLUTION:** Anand's solution below (removing the keychain reference) appears to be right. I checked the print statement at the beginning of toggleStatus() and it included a reference to a keychain item, which was causing the crash.  The difference between this keychain reference and the ones in the didUpdate function was that it was stored in a keychain created with SwiftKeychainWrapper.  I ran into some other problems with SwiftKeychainWrapper earlier when  developing the app and switched to KeychainSwift when I wrote the rest of the code.  For reasons of pure laziness (this app is just for me) I never went back and switched the value in toggleStatus() over.  Removing the reference allowed toggleStatus() to continue.  I'm still changing everything over but this seems to have solved the problem.

Comment: What's the complete error message from the crash? Which line exactly is causing the crash?

Comment: Is Capabilities > Background modes > Location Updates enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are storing location details in Keychain. Accessing keychain when the app is in suspended state will not be always error free. It's behavior is totally weird for background cases. When Touch ID / Face ID is enabled in the device, it makes the case more complicated when the device is locked.

Let's say, your device has Touch ID / Face ID enabled and device is locked. Now, when the app receives location update, it will try to access keychain but the device is locked with Touch ID / Face ID enabled. This kind of combination will sometimes work and sometimes will not. Still, i am searching why this happens.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this answer is right.  I checked the print statement at the beginning of toggleStatus() and it included a reference to keychain item, which was stopping  I removed it and toggleStatus continued on until it hit another keychain item.  I'm reworking now but pretty sure removing the keychain references fixes the issue.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. If you think it’s right, please upvote and accept the answer

Comment: I can't upvote yet.  Apparently you need a reputation score (I'm pretty new).  But looks like someone did.  Thanks again for the solution!

Comment: Thanks Jeff. But you can accept the answer. Please check